# How to return letters from UTF-16

Tags: javascript

I need to return the letters in a word in alphabetical order. I got the following problem, I don't know how to return the letters from numbers, I tried to use `String.fromCharCode()` and `charAt()` but it did nothing.
I got:

```
function AlphabetSoup(str) { 

  let spl = str.split('');
let res = spl.map(order => order.charCodeAt()).sort((a,b) => b - a).reverse();

 return res;
}
```

So the result is `[ 98, 99, 100, 101, 101, 111, 114, 116, 121 ]`

Comment: please ask your question little bit clearly

Comment: How to change numbers in an array to the letters through utf 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) already orders values by their UTF-16 string representation.

> The default sort order is built upon converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values.

```js
function AlphabetSoup(str) {
  return str.split('').sort();
}

var r = AlphabetSoup("HelloWorld");
console.log(r);
```

If you were insistent upon using your proposed method, you could re-`map` the values back to their string representation using `String.fromCharCode()`.

```js
function AlphabetSoup(str) {

  let spl = str.split('');
  let res = spl
    .map(order => order.charCodeAt())
    .sort((a, b) => a-b)
    .map(order => String.fromCharCode(order));

  return res;
}

var r = AlphabetSoup("HelloWorld");
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(AlphabetSoup('hello'))
console.log(AlphabetSoup2('hello'))

/* Given what you gave, you have to convert it back */
function AlphabetSoup(str) {
  let spl = str.split('');
  let res = spl.map(char => char.charCodeAt())
               .sort((a, b) => b - a)
               .reverse()
               .map(ascii=>String.fromCharCode(ascii))  // <-- convert back
               .join('');                               // <-- make it a string

  return res;
}


/* Of course string comparison natively works on ASCII values */
function AlphabetSoup2(str) {
  let arr = str.split('');
  return arr.sort((a, b) => b < a).join('');             // <-- notice the '<'
}
```

Of course, `sort()` be default does what you want so you could be less explicit (and more accurate) by doing `return arr.sort().join('')`